# Meteor won't publish collection with id's of type ObjectID

Tags: meteor

One of my collections contains documents with ObjectID's instead of Meteor style _ids's that are generated by Random.id().

I get error output in the server console saying `'Error: Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids'` when I try to publish/subscribe to a subset of the collection.

This used to work fine, but appears to be problematic in Meteor 1.4.3.2. Does anyone have a pointer how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please post your actual code

Comment: What is `Random.id()`? This isn't a standard javascript or mongodb function.  Is it coming from a meteor or npm package?

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb supports the _id field as a normal field, like this:

```
{
    _id: "sa09d8asd98asd9sad8",
    otherfield: "jdlskfjsdlk"
}
```

And supports the _id field as an ObjectID field, like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectID("sa09d8asd98asd9sad8"),
    otherfield: "jdlskfjsdlk"
}
```

But in Meteor Apps, the _id field as an ObjectID is not supported and it will not work in publications and subscriptions functions. You will need to change your ObjectID's fields for normal _ids fields.

Comment: I always use the meteor default of strings, but unless something has changed, you can use `ObjectID` if you want.  You just have to set the `idGeneration` option when you define your collection.  Check this out [here](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection)

Comment: Yes you can. It turned out that the meteor-id package does not support documents that are created by the latest versions of the Node MongoDB driver. In these documents ObjectID contains a Buffer instead of the actual string id (_str).In order to make it work, I had to overload the mongo-id package and parse this Buffer to a hex string.